# Enterprise Architect: TaggedValues in Diagrams?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I would like to add a tagged value to a diagram in C#. Is this possible? Unfortunately the "New Tagged Value" button is disabled in the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

There are no tagged values for diagrams. (and with good reason)
You'll need to find and object that is somehow represented by this diagram and use that.

Comment: Can you explain or at least list what are the "good reasons"?

Comment: @xmojmr If you look at the UML metamodel you will see that tagged values are actually instances of properties on a stereotype. Stereotypes can be applied to model elements. But since Diagrams are no model elements they shouldn't even be allowed to have stereotypes, let alone tagged values.